# Breaking down a string and putting it into array using strtok()

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I'm writing a basic program that takes a CSV file, prints the first field, and does some numerical evaluation of the other fields.

I'm looking to put all the numerical fields into an array but every time I do this and try to access a random element of the array, it prints the entire thing

My CSV file is:

```
Exp1,10,12,13
Exp2,15,16,19
```

and i'm trying to access the second field so it prints

```
Exp1 12
Exp2 16
```

but instead I'm getting

```
Exp1 101213
Exp2 151619
```

If someone could provide some suggestions. This is my code:

```
#define DELIM ","

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if(argc == 2) {
         FILE *txt_file;
         txt_file = fopen(argv[1], "rt");

         if(!txt_file) {
             printf("File does not exist.\n");
             return 1;
         }

         char tmp[4096];
         char data[4096];
         char expName[100];
         char *tok;
         int i;

         while(1){
             if(!fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), txt_file)) break;

             //prints the experiment name
             tok = strtok(tmp, DELIM);
             strncpy(expName, tok, sizeof(expName));
             printf("\n%s ", expName);

             while(tok != NULL) {
                 tok = strtok(NULL, DELIM);

                //puts data fields into an array
                for(i=0; i < sizeof(data); i++) {
                     if(tok != NULL) {
                          data[i] = atoi(tok);
                     }
                }
                printf("%d", data[1]);
             }
        }
 fclose(txt_file);
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample to fix

```
 char tmp[4096];
 int data[2048];
 char expName[100];
 char *tok;
 int i=0;

 while(fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), txt_file)){
     tok = strtok(tmp, DELIM);
     strncpy(expName, tok, sizeof(expName));
     printf("\n%s ", expName);

     while((tok = strtok(NULL, DELIM))!=NULL){
         data[i++] = atoi(tok);
    }
    printf("%d", data[1]);
    i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified code snippet:

```
     int data[20]; // change 20 to a reasonable value
...
     while (1)
     {   if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), txt_file))
             break;

         //prints the experiment name
         tok = strtok(tmp, DELIM);
         strncpy(expName, tok, sizeof(expName));
         printf("\n%s ", expName);

         i = 0;
         tok = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
         while (tok != NULL)
         {  //puts data fields into an array
            data[i++] = atoi(tok);
            if (i == 20)
                break;
            tok = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
         }
         if (i > 1)
            printf("%d", data[1]);
     }
```